# Active Reports 7 - Grand Total of each row in Detail Section

Tags: activereports

I have a report in which I need to calculate some totals for each rows in detail. I need to get the DataField 'Movie_Code' of each and make a sum of his columns to have a grand total at the end of the page. The code can be in multiple places since it's regrouped by Client.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to display the GrandTotal for the details rows on each page then I would suggest you to place a textbox in the PageFooter section and set the following properties for it:

**DataField**: Movie_Code
**SummaryFunction**: SUM
**SummaryRunning**: All
**SummaryType**: GrandTotal

This will show the total of each rows in the detail section for the current page and the detail rows on the previous pages.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add the GroupHeader/Groupfooter sections and the Summary field in the GroupFooter. 
Set the DataField property for GroupFooter Section and then place a textbox in GroupFooter and set the SummaryType and Summaryfunction properties. Refer to the given link for details :
http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/AR7Help/OnlineEn/CreateaSummaryReport.html

You may add the field in the detail section itself and set the mentioned properties accordingly.

Regards,
Mohita